# Videoview is not displaying in nougat 24 but displaying and working in android Q 29

Tags: android, android-layout, android-videoview, android-fullscreen

I'm working application. when button click happens, it displays popup window with videoview. It is showing in android 29 api, but not in android 24 api. the following is the code of showvideopopup function for it.

```
private void showVideoPopup()
    {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View customView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.dispensing_intro,null);

        int uiOptions =View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY;
        customView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);


//        closePopupBtn = (Button) customView.findViewById(R.id.closeView);

        //instantiate popup window
        dispense_intro_popup = new PopupWindow(customView, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

        //display the popup window
        dispense_intro_popup.showAtLocation(dispense_intro_view, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);

        VideoView video = (VideoView) customView.findViewById(R.id.dispense_intro);
        Uri videoUri = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/raw/"+ R.raw.dispense_intro);
        video.setVideoURI(videoUri);
        video.start();

        video.setOnCompletionListener(this);

    }
```

The Following is the popup.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="#b3000000"
    android:layout_height="700dp"
    android:id="@+id/dispense_intro_holder"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center">


    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/dispense_intro"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="640dp"
        android:layout_height="360dp"  />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: 2 questions, `1` Are you seeing any errors / stacktraces? or is it just plain not showing any video? and `2` Try logging what the video URI is before you call `.start()` just to see if that is different for any reason.

Comment: NO, I'm not seeing any stack traces.

Comment: I'm able to log the video uri

Comment: @Silmarilos Could please look into this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `DialogFragment()` instead of `PopupWindow`.

Then add the following code to fragment `onCreateView`

PopupFragment.java

```
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.popup, container, false);
        setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NO_TITLE, R.style.FullscreenTheme);
        VideoView video = (VideoView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.dispense_intro);
        Uri videoUri = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/raw/"+ R.raw.dispense_intro);
        video.setVideoURI(videoUri);
        video.start();

        video.setOnCompletionListener(this);

        return rootView;

}
```

And to make dialog fragment to full screen use the following code for `onDialogCreated`

```
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Dialog dialog = super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);
        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

        dialog.getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                        // Hide the nav bar and status bar
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        return dialog;
    }
```